# Dominion - Can you trash horses?

Tags: dominion

In the game [dominion](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/36218/dominion) are you allowed to trash [horses](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Horse) with say a card like [improve](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Improve)?

On the card it states it is not part of the supply.

Is there any place in the rules that states that you can or can not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.

There is nothing about being part of the supply that affects trashing; they are still "cards" and thus are affected by things that talk about cards.

The rules for trashing from the [base game rulebook](https://www.riograndegames.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Dominion-2nd-Edition-Rules.pdf) don't say anything that would restrict it to supply cards:

> "Trash a card" - Put a card into the Trash pile.
>
> > This is a way of getting rid of a card; a trashed card is no longer one of your cards.

"Gaining" is different because of the rules for gaining itself; the rules for "gain a card" include that the card must be from the supply unless specifically said otherwise.

> "Gain a card" - Take a card from the Supply and put it into your discard pile.
>
> > Sometimes a card will let you gain a card from a place other than the Supply, but by default
> > gained cards come from the Supply.

Now, your specific example of Improve and Horses is tricky because normally you wouldn't have a Horse in play at the start of cleanup; since it returns itself to its pile when you play it. But with things like Ways from Menagerie, there are ways to do it.

Comment: If you simply didn't play the horse wouldn't it just stay in your hand to be disgarded at the end of the turn?

Comment: @silent-tiger That is covered in your link.  there is a note from the designer stating "you don't have to play it; you can Remodel it".  So if you don't have to play it then it would be discarded from your hand during clean up

Comment: @silent-tiger You could keep a Horse in your hand and then discard it like normal at the end of the turn, but Improve only trashes cards from play; it can't be used to trash cards from your hand.

Comment: Oh good point, I get it. I also get the ways comment now.